# Ubuntu cannot boot because no valid partition table. How to fix it?

Tags: boot, partition, partition-table

I am unable to boot. I have only Ubuntu installed on a computer, and it was working fine. But suddenly I am unable to boot. It says "no valid partition table".

I have attached the output I received when I issue the command "fdisk -l". I am not very familiar with Ubuntu. Therefore any help is appreciated.

[image: Output of fdisk -l]

Comment: What is in your fstab? (Looks like your /boot and root partition are in the sda drive. You can mount it from rescue mode or from the live linux.) 
(Put the output in your question please.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have deleted the disk’s partition table.  Do you know if you or someone who has access to the computer might have writing to the disk as a super user?

Try a tool like [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the partition table.  Otherwise, you are going to have to reinstall your OS and restore from backups any data you need.  If the data loss wasn’t due to someone accidentally writing over the partition table, you might also want to make sure the disk isn’t failing.